# spring-config-client received multiple refresh event when ever there is a change in consumer-group-name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-cloud-config-client

i am using spring cloud config server, kafka, git and spring cloud bus for to auto-refresh my client properties but when ever i am restarting my client application first time by changing consumer-group-name then i observed that during startup my client application Received remote refresh request multiple times which is equal to the no of times i have committed my client properties changes , but i want to avoid such multiple refresh request during startup.

'spring.cloud.stream.default.group' is the property which i used to define the
consumer-group-name at client application.